# Why am I getting this laravel url routing error in .htaccess?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have recently installed Laravel into my public_html folder.  I want it so when I log into www.malhub.com it gets the contents of the public folder `(public_html/public).`

After trial and error, I was able to get it working somewhat.  Now I have a 404 error, which is caused because the site (www.malhub.com) resolves to :

```
http://malhub.com/public/public_html
```

But my .htaccess code states:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/public/$1 [L]
```

In other words, it looks for a public_html folder within the public folder (should just be the public folder)

I added some folders (test) just to make sense of how this works and am befuddled.  It is going into the public folder and looking for another folder.

When I just try writing:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

or "public_html" or any combination of /../../ I keep getting 500 errors (that don't show the url).

How does this line of code work, and what is the optimum way?

Comment: Your application is running in http://malhub.com/public/

Comment: By default your application index page will load from public folder..so the url would be `malhub.com/public`

Comment: @RashedHasan I see, how do I get it so that it shortens the URL?  I want malhub.com to resolve to malhub.com/public (without typing "public").  I suppose I can change it in my domain settings, but is there an easier way via .htacess?  Thanks.

Comment: @jitheshjose I understand, my question is how do I change it so when someone types "malhub.com" it resolves to the /public directory?

Comment: try the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the website will be load from public folder.
If you want to remove public from your url,copy `.htaccess` file from `public` folder to root and replace the code with the following..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my next question, you can disregard the other reply, I noted yours as correct.

Comment: Just one minor tweak, I changed "server.php" to "index.php" (I don't have a server.php).  Well now I am all set to start developing!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to remove all files and folder from the `public` folder, then just copy `.htaccess` to your root directory and rename `server.php` to `index.php` and last one step is if all resource files in `/public` directory couldn't find and request URLs didn't work for using `asset()` helper. Then, you need to add `public` to your `helpers.php` file.

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
}
```

To

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
}
```

You will fine the `helpers.php` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`.